# Can you re-provision a device through Azure Device Provisioning Service using MQTT directly?

Tags: azure, service, device, iot, provisioning

I am designing a solution for connected devices and have a requirement to re-provision a device before sending a message to ensure it is always connected to the nearest IoT Hub (based on latency).

Based on the Microsoft documentation, it is possible to register a device using MQTT by publishing a message to the DPS. However, is it possible to re-provision a device with MQTT?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support

Also, when registering a device for the first time via MQTT, is there a topic to subscribe to obtain the connection of the IoT Hub that DPS assigned the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The same [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support#registering-a-device) (Register message) triggers re-provisioning. The device is unaware as to whether it is being provisioned or re-provisioned.

The results of provisioning (or re-provisioning) including the name of the IotHub and the corresponding credential are published in the [DeviceRegistrationResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/runtimeregistration/registerdevice#deviceregistrationresult)
object. This object is part of the [RegistrationOperationStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/runtimeregistration/registerdevice#registrationoperationstatus) object returned in response to the [get-operation-status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support#polling-for-registration-operation-status) operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasn't aware that we could publish a message to the retrieve the operation status. The documentation doesn't make it that clear.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/iot-dps-mqtt-support#polling-for-registration-operation-status) you are referring to, you can subscribe to `dps/registrations/res/#` to be notified of the progress of your (re-)registration request.